# looking for a compiled version of postgreSQL 9.5 for rpi 2

Tags: database

Has anyone installed postgres 9.5, the new release on a raspberry pi?

`sudo apt-get install postgres` installs 9.4.5 at the moment..

Comment: I have not seen a compiled version of 9.5 for either RPi models. Compiling 9.5 yourself will be fairly complicated, and will take a long time. If you don't absolutely need the latest version, I'd stick with the older.

Comment: hum, I need to run some sql scripts with some upsert.. will be waiting till someone compiles it I guess.

Comment: It will probably be a lengthy wait. PostgreSQL 9.5 was just released on January 7th, and Arch Linux doesn't even have it in the primary branch of x86_64, let alone arm.

Comment: is there a reason you can't compile it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You could upgrade to the `stretch` version of Raspbian, it includes postgres 9.5 atm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Arch linux, the official repo now supports version `9.5.2-1`. The version in the Raspbian repos is still 9.4 unfortunately.